# Как загрузить изображение на HTML страницу?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

При выборе изображения нужно загрузить его на HTML страницу.
Изображение на странице не отображается( Как исправить?

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="Photo" name="Photo" accept="image/*" onchange="previewPhoto(this)"/>
<img id="previewPhoto" class="previewPhoto" src="~/App_Files/Images/default.png"/>
```

Сначала загружаю фото по ссылке, потом его нужно заменить на выбранное изображение

Javascript

```
    function previewPhoto(photo) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function () {
            var output = document.getElementById('previewPhoto');
            output.src = reader.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(photo.target.files[0]);
    }
```

Comment: я точно не уверен но по моему загружать на сервер должен серверный язык программирования .. вопрос больше к php относится

Comment: @МаксимЛенский не на сервер а на странице отобразить

Comment: т.е изображение будет храниться не на сервере а где то из вне ?

Comment: я тег один не прочитал - прошу прощения , asp не моё

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function previewPhoto() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('#previewPhoto');
  var file = document.querySelector('input#Photo[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function() {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    preview.src = "";
  }
}
```

```css
#previewPhoto {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="Photo" name="Photo" accept="image/*" onchange="previewPhoto()" />
<img id="previewPhoto" class="previewPhoto" src="~/App_Files/Images/default.png" />
```

[объект FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

[пример взят здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087076/how-to-make-a-simple-image-upload-using-javascript-html)

Comment: Выдает ошибку
Uncaught TypeError: previewPhoto is not a function at HtmlInputElement.onchange

Comment: ищите ошибке в исходном коде - пример-то рабочий.