# Предпросмотр картинки выбранной через <input type="file">?

Tags: jquery, html5

Как реализовать предпросмотр картинки, выбранной через  до отправки формы?
Написал такой скрипт:

```
<script>
                $(document).ready(function previewImage() {
                    $("#imageField").bind("change", function () {
                        $('#image').attr('src', this.value);
                        return true;
                    });
                });
</script>
```

Выводится ошибка: `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/fakepath/logo.png`
Есть решение?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811540/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-html-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83/811552#811552

Comment: @Kirill FileReader красивое решение ☝